# How to pick a random english word from a list

Tags: python, random, word-list

What would be the best way to go about getting a function that returns a random English word (preferably a noun), without keeping a list of all possible words in a file before hand?

Comment: This isn't a sensible question.  Could you provide some additional context or clue as to what you're trying to do.  Generating English words without an English dictionary is a logical contradiction.  Please clarify this.

Comment: fetching a word from any online resource designed to provide random words looks like a good idea. :-)

Comment: @joshhunt: What constitutes "massive"?  Spellcheck dictionaries for English are about 400K.  See http://aspell.net/ for a good one.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Word lists need not take up all that much space.

Here's a [JSON wordlist with 2,465 words, all nouns](https://www.randomlists.com/data/words.json).  It clocks in at under 50K, the size of a medium-sized jpeg image.

I'll leave choosing a random one as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: This really is the best option. You could easily keep the entire list in memory and you'll have complete control over the source -- no unexpected changes, no connection issues, no security concerns, and overall should be much easier to implement.

Comment: And you don't even need to keep it all in memory.

Answer (score 10):

You can't. There is no algorithm to generate meaningful words. You can only generate words that sound like English, but they won't have any meaning.

Comment: While hobarattically trice, you can still grat a finth.

Answer (score 4):

You could have the function try and parse an online resource such as:

http://www.zokutou.co.uk/randomword/

Comment: Please fix broken link

Answer (score 3):

Another theoretical approach: you could scrape the [random wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random) page and return the N-th word of the article.

Comment: It's a nice idea, but you might need to filter out dates and numbers and non-Engilsh words.

Comment: The results wouldn't be very random -- you'd tend to get the same few words a lot, and all sorts of other problems.

Comment: @Whatsit I guess you're right. On the other hand: what des random english word really mean? If you ask somebody for a random word, it will be a similar statistical distribution

Answer (score 2):

Just use setgetgo's random word api. It's free, it's easy, and it rocks.

http://randomword.setgetgo.com/

Comment: Responce return real words, but and return non-real words

Answer (score 1):

There's a random word generator [here](http://randword.lukesampson.com/) - it's not English but it's English-ish, i.e. the words are similar enough to language that a user can read the words and store them in short-term memory.

Source code is in C# and a bit kludged, but you could use a similar approach in Python to generate lots of words without having to store a massive list.

Alternatively, you could call the web service on the demo page directly - it's hosted on GoDaddy though, so no guarantees it will work in production!

Answer (score 1):

You can download the "words common to SOWPODS and TWL" lists from http://www.math.toronto.edu/jjchew/scrabble/lists/ . I put all the words in those files together and the list weighed in at about 642k. Not huge by any standards. The lists do contain a whole lot of obscure words though, since they are meant for tournament Scrabble use. The good thing is that the lists form a substantial subset of the English language.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have three options:

- Hard-code the list of words and initialize an array with it.
- Fetch the list from an internet location instead of a file.
- Keep a list of possible words in a file.

The only way to avoid the above is if you're not concerned whether the word is real: you can just generate random-length strings of characters. (There's no way to programmatically generate words without a dictionary list to go from.)