# which module will give me plenty words so that i can use them for my hangman project

Tags: python, dictionary, module, cpu-word

I am asking, like is there any **module** that will provide me the words so that I can have plenty of words that never repeat for a user. Is there any dictionary module.

Comment: On a unix-like OS `/usr/share/dict/words` will contain a list of words you can use...

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
Asking for resource recommendations or references is specifically off topic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a module that does that, but what I'd do to solve this is go here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/594963/3045171

And just import that json into my project. That's about 5,000 words.